# Corr between every nth variable

Tags: r, loops, iteration, correlation

I have a long list of multiple columns representing different variables over time. I am trying to run a correlation between each of the three time points e.g.

```
cor(df1[,c(7,36,65)], use = "p")
cor(df1[,c(8,37,66)], use = "p")
cor(df1[,c(9,38,67)], use = "p")
```

This is time consuming and I want to be able to run this if I add / remove columns in the near future. As you can see, it obviously follows a pattern and I have tried achieving this using apply:

```
apply(df1[,c(7:93)], 2, function(x) corr(df1[,c(x, x+29, x+58)], use = "p"))
```

I've also tried a for loop:

```
for (i in 7:93) {
  cor(df1[, c(i,i+29,i+58)], use = "p")
}
```

Obviously I am making mistakes in my writing of both of these. I know there has to be an easy way to do this that I am missing!

Comment: Just use the `seq` i.e `lapply(7:9, function(i) corr(df1[seq(i, ncol(df1), by = 29)], use = "p"))` You can check the output of `lapply(7:9, function(i) seq(i, ncol(df1), by = 29))`

Comment: Another option is a `split` method `lapply(split.default(df2, (seq_along(df2)-1) %% 29), cor, use = "p")` where 'df2' is `df2 <- df1[-(1:6)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mapply` for selecting the columns in parallel.

```
mapply(function(x, y, z) cor(df1[,c(x, y, z)], use = "p"), 7:35, 36:64, 65:93)
```

---

Or taking your attempt ahead another solution similar to that of @akrun's could be

```
sapply(7:35, function(x) cor(df1[,c(x, x+29, x+58)], use = "p"))
```